# Create a list of how often violations occured based on resultID

Tags: mysql, join, sum, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to create a list of violations and how often they occurred based on the relationship between my 'violation' table and my 'result' table.

The relationship between the two is that resultID column is the primary key of the 'result' table, and the result_resultID column is the foreign key in the 'violation' table.

Im trying to group them by violationID, and I need a sum of how many times certain results occured.

My DB Schema Script is as followed:

-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
```

---

```
-- Schema jocutraffic
```

---

---

```
-- Table `offender`
```

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `offender` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `offender` (
`offenderID` INT NOT NULL,
`firstname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`lastname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`address` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`city` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`state` VARCHAR(2) NULL,
`numberoftickets` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`offenderID`),
UNIQUE INDEX `offenderID_UNIQUE` (`offenderID` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

```
-- Table `vehicle`
```

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `vehicle` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vehicle` (
`vehicleLiscense` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
`state` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
`color` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`year` YEAR NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`make` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`type` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`vin` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`owner` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`address` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`offenderID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`vehicleLiscense`, `offenderID`),
INDEX `fk_vehicle_offender_idx` (`offenderID` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_vehicle_offender`
FOREIGN KEY (`offenderID`)
REFERENCES `offender` (`offenderID`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

```
-- Table `result`
```

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `result` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `result` (
`resultID` INT NOT NULL,
`description` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`resultID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

```
-- Table `officer`
```

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `officer` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `officer` (
`officerID` INT NOT NULL,
`firstname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`lastname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`officerID`),
UNIQUE INDEX `lastname_UNIQUE` (`lastname` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

```
-- Table `violation`
```

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `violation` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `violation` (
`violationID` INT NOT NULL,
`vehicle_vehicleLiscense` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
`offenderID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`violationMonth` INT(2) NOT NULL,
`violationDay` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
`violationYear` YEAR NOT NULL,
`result_resultID` INT NOT NULL,
`officer_officerID` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`violationID`, `vehicle_vehicleLiscense`, `offenderID`),
INDEX `fk_violation_vehicle1_idx` (`vehicle_vehicleLiscense` ASC, `offenderID` ASC),
INDEX `fk_violation_result1_idx` (`result_resultID` ASC),
INDEX `fk_violation_officer1_idx` (`officer_officerID` ASC),
UNIQUE INDEX `violationID_UNIQUE` (`violationID` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_violation_vehicle1`
FOREIGN KEY (`vehicle_vehicleLiscense` , `offenderID`)
REFERENCES `vehicle` (`vehicleLiscense` , `offenderID`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_violation_result1`
FOREIGN KEY (`result_resultID`)
REFERENCES `result` (`resultID`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_violation_officer1`
FOREIGN KEY (`officer_officerID`)
REFERENCES `officer` (`officerID`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Here are some screenshots of data that I have inserted into the tables for example and a a greater understanding.

[image]
[image]

I know I probably need a join statement here but, im having trouble making this work with the aggregate SUM function. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: We cant copy paste from pictures so include the proper db schema. Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
    And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 
 this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Juan, and thank you for the prompt and quick response. Hopefully the Schema script clears up any confusion or ambiguities.

Comment: schema is good, but we also need sample data and desire output as explain on the link I offer you. Also there is a good tool to share schema with data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c876c. Just add the inserts at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will give you the total of each result, you dont need the `vehicule` join to get result, but i leave in case you question is different.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c876c/2)**

```
SELECT re.`description`, count(*)
FROM `violation` vi
JOIN `vehicle` ve
  ON vi.`vehicle_vehicleLiscense` = ve.`vehicleLiscense`
 AND vi.`offenderID` = ve.`offenderID`
JOIN `result` re
  ON vi.`result_resultID` = re.`resultID`
GROUP BY re.`description`
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help man! I really appreciate it. I'm new to learning SQL, and I appreciate your patience.